# Can't Extract Specific Value (variable) from an Array in PERL

Tags: perl

DATA FILE temp.csv

> 1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,
>
> 2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,
>
> 3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,
>
> 4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,
>
> 5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87,

I want to extract `(column 6) value if  (column 3 = 09:00:00)`

push to `$result` variable.  This needs to be the specific value/variable not an array.  I need to do additional calculations with that value and move it to a database.  Here is the code I used but I can't extract the specific value to a variable.

```
 my @temp_9 = map {
 chomp;
 my @t_fh_9 = split /,/;
 sprintf "%.0f", $t_fh_9[6] if $t_fh_9[2] eq '09:00:00';
 } <$ft1>;
```

When I attempt to subtract or do other math the numbers are nonsensical.

Comment: Your sample code compares the column with `9:00:00` -- is the missing leading zero an error in your paste or your code?

Comment: typo  - above does work however the problem remains as its an array

Comment: Don't use `map` when you want to `grep`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür At first glance that would seem to be the case, but it's not. `grep` is fine when you want to filter a list, but when you want to filter and transform it's not appropriate. Especially if the filter and transform have to do the same data processing (split the CSV line).

Comment: @SinanÜnür To avoid parsing the CSV line multiple times you need a `map, grep, map`. First `map` parses the line, then `grep` filters for the lines in question, and second `map` extracts just the desired column. At that point a while loop is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems one of the sources of confusion is extracting an element from an array. An array is zero or more scalar elements - you can't just assign one to the other, because .... well, what should happen if there isn't just one element (which is the usual case).

Given an array, we can:

- `pop @array` will return the last element (and remove it from the array) so you could `my $result = pop @array;`
- `[0]` is the first element of the array, so we can `my $result = $array[0];`
- Or we can assign one array to another: `my ( $result ) = @array;` - because on the left hand side we have an array now, and it's a single element - the first element of `@array` goes into `$result`. (The rest isn't used in this scenario - but you could do `my ( $result, @anything_else ) = @array;`

So in your example - if what you're trying to do is retrieve a value matching a criteria - the normal tool for the job would be `grep` - which filters an array by applying a conditional test to each element.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @lines = grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print "@lines";
print $lines[0];

__DATA__
1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,
2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,
3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,
4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,
5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87
```

Which we can reduce to:

```
my ( $firstresult ) = grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print $firstresult;
```

But as we want to want to transform our array - `map` is the tool for the job.

```
my ( $result ) = map { (split /,/)[6] - 273.15 } grep { (split /,/)[2] eq "12:00:00" } <DATA>;
print $result;
```

First we:

- use grep to extract the matching elements. (one in this case, but doesn't necessarily have to be!)
- use map to transform the list, so that that we turn each element into just it's 6th field, and subtract 273.15
- assign the whole lot to a list containing a single element - in effect just taking the first result, and throwing the rest away.

Or perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($result) = map {
          ( split /,/ )[2] eq "12:00:00"
        ? ( split /,/ )[6] - 273.15
        : ()
} <DATA>;
print $result;
```

But personally, I think that's getting a bit complicated and may be hard to understand. `map` is a powerful function, but can lead to code that's hard to read for future maintenance programmers.

So I would suggest instead:

```
my $result;
while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;
    if ( $fields[2] eq "12:00:00" ) {
        $result = $fields[6] - 273.15;
        last;
    }
}

print $result;
```

Iterate your data, split - and test - each line, and when you find one that matches the criteria - set `$result` and bail out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`map` always has a one to one mapping, if you put 10 things in, you will get a list of 10 things out.  What you want is a while loop which selectively pushes onto an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my @nines;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /,/;
    next unless $row[2] eq '09:00:00';
    push @nines, sprintf("%.0f", $row[6]);
}

say join ", ", @nines;

__DATA__
1,2015-08-20,00:00:00,89,1007.48,295.551,296.66,
2,2015-08-20,03:00:00,85,1006.49,295.947,296.99,
3,2015-08-20,06:00:00,86,1006.05,295.05,296.02,
4,2015-08-20,09:00:00,85,1005.87,296.026,296.93,
5,2015-08-20,12:00:00,77,1004.96,298.034,298.87,
```

From your variable names like `@temp_9` and `@t_fh_9`, I suspect you're hard coding the variable name with the particular time of day.  This will lead to a lot of code duplication.  Instead, write a little function that takes the time of day you're looking for.

```
sub extract_column_for_time_of_day {
    my($fh, $column_number, $time_of_day) = @_;

    my @extracts;
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my @row = split /,/;
        next unless $row[2] eq $time_of_day;
        push @extracts, sprintf("%.0f", $row[$column_number]);
    }

    return @extracts;
}

say join ", ", extract_column_for_time_of_day(\*DATA, 6, '09:00:00');
```

Finally, I'm guessing you're going to get data for various times.  This will lead to a pile of variables which will be awkward to pass around as a unit.  Instead of having a variable for each time, put each list into a hash.

```
my $time = '09:00:00'; 
$extracts{$time} = [extract_column_for_time_of_day(\*DATA, 6, $time)];
```

Comment: *"`map` always has a one to one mapping, if you put 10 things in, you will get a list of 10 things out"* is misleading as tose *things* may be multi-element lists or empty lists. `map {  $_ > 2 ? ($_, $_, $_) : ()  } 1, 2, 3, 4` generates the six-element list `3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4`

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function typically returns a list with the same number of elements as the source, *unless* you return an empty or multi-element list. In fact, one of the first examples in the `map` perl doc's shows how to do this, once again proving you should always check the docs first.

```
my @temp_9 = map {
    chomp;
    my @t_fh_9 = split /,/;
    $t_fh_9[2] eq '09:00:00' ? ( $t_fh_9[6] ) : ();
} <$ft1>;
```

Comment: The "my ( $result ) = map" by Sobrique was the syntax that saved the day.   The array was killing me, though it was producing the desired value at first blush, I was not able to use that variable in further calculations or functions. The above syntax has given me that much needed flexibility.  Thanks everyone for your help and thanks Sobrique.